# How to change tab while progress bar is being updated in QT

Tags: qt, tabs, progress-bar, qwidget

I have a Qwidget with a few tabs. In one of the tabs, after clicking a button, a function starts processing data and updates a progress bar.

I'd like to be able to change tabs while this process is running, currently it does'nt let me do so. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You must use a modeless progressdialog insteal of modal one. Practically, the main event loop must get the control to allow user interaction.
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QProgressDialog_Modal_Modeless_QTimer.php

(2) You should put your data processing function to worker thread and invoke a progress dialog update to main UI thread from that. That way your task would not block UI, so you could interact with the window (like changing tab) meanwhile.

- Qt also provides means to implement this, you might want to refer to:

  - `QFuture`, `QtConcurrent::run()`: run a task in separate thread.
  - `QFutureWatcher`: help monitor the progress of a task running in worker thread.
    Example: 
    http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-progressdialog-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Below logic may help you.

1. You can achieve this by using QThread.
2. Move the process to a separate thread(assume as **worker thread**)
3. So now there will be two thread (1. main thread & 2.worker thread)
4. Execute the process from **worker thread**
5. Use signal & slot mechanism to communicate between the main thread(1) & worker thread(2) (to update GUI and or to do some process)
6. This logic will stop the application from getting hanged.
7. Refer this [link](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) to know in detail.

You can get the sample application [here](https://github.com/tryagainworks/StackOverflow/tree/master/TabWithMultiThread), which follow the above said logic

Application screen shot :
[image]

Start Progress(Thread) : Start the thread and do process
Stop Process (Thread) : Stop the thread